# comparing dataframes to import incremental data in spark and scala issue

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hivecontext

I have derived a dataframe from oracle using `Sqlcontext` and I have registered it as temp table `tb1`.

I have another dataframe which is derived from hive using `HiveContext` and I registered this as table `tb2`.

When I am trying to access these two tables using `HiveContext` I am getting the error like `Unable to find tb1 and when try it with sqlcontext`.

I am getting error like `Unable to find tb2`.

Any help on this please.

I'm doing it in Scala of-course.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: If you created separate `HiveContext` and `SQLContext` - you shouldn't - HiveContext extends SQLContext so it has all of its abilities. Create a single HiveContext _only_ and use it to create both tables.